# Variável infinita (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Estou a programar no: http://alpha.editor.p5js.org

O exercício: sempre que o utilizador prime a tecla 'A' é atribuído um número aleatório entre 1 e 6 assim como se primir a tecla 'B'. Preciso de fazer a comparação entre esses dois números de modo a perceber qual é o maior e atribuir 1 ponto ao utilizador que primiu a tecla 'A' ou 'B' respetivamente.

O que me acontece é que quando primo a tecla, na parte dos pontos fica a aumentar a pontuação infinitamente, ainda antes do segundo utilizador ter primido a sua tecla e o computador ter feito a comparação.

```
var s = "Pontos A";
var r = "Pontos B";
var d1 = 0;
var d2 = 0;
var pontosA = 0;
var pontosB = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 65) {
    d1 = 1 + int((6 - 1 + 1) * random());
  } else if (keyCode === 66) {
    d2 = 1 + int((6 - 1 + 1) * random());
  }
  return false;
}

function draw() {
  if (d1 > d2) {
    pontosA = pontosA + 1;
  }
  if (d2 > d1) {
    pontosB = pontosB + 1;
  }
  background(220);
  text(s, 50, 10, 70, 80);
  text(r, 300, 10, 80, 80);

  text(pontosA, 60, 50);
  text(pontosB, 320, 50);
  text(d1, 60, 100);
  text(d2, 320, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No editor que mencionou, o http://alpha.editor.p5js.org, a função `draw` é executada várias vezes por segundo, sempre que for necessário atualizar a tela. Logo não pode fazer a atualização dos pontos nela, senão atualiza inúmeras vezes sem interação do usuário.

O local ideal para essa atualização seria então na função `keyPressed`, que executa apenas uma vez, quando o usuário prime a tecla. Transportando o seu código de atualização de pontos para a função `keyPressed` já funciona:

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 65) {
    d1 = 1 + int((6 - 1 + 1) * random());

    //atualiza aqui
    if (d1 > d2) { 
        pontosA = pontosA + 1;
    }
    if (d2 > d1) {
        pontosB = pontosB + 1;
    }
  } else if (keyCode === 66) {
    d2 = 1 + int((6 - 1 + 1) * random());

    //e aqui também
    if (d1 > d2) {
        pontosA = pontosA + 1;
    }
    if (d2 > d1) {
        pontosB = pontosB + 1;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function draw() {
  //sem atualização de pontos aqui
  background(220);
  text(s, 50, 10, 70, 80);
  text(r, 300, 10, 80, 80);

  text(pontosA, 60, 50);
  text(pontosB, 320, 50);
  text(d1, 60, 100);
  text(d2, 320, 100);
}
```

Repare no entanto que há uma certa lógica repetida no código. Sempre que se vê a repetir código é porque tem forma melhor de o escrever. Neste caso uma melhor solução seria transformar aquele código repetido numa função que pode chamar em quer o usuário prima `A` ou `B`:

```
function atualizaPontos(){
  if (d1 > d2) {
    pontosA = pontosA + 1;
  }
  else if (d2 > d1) { //else if em vez de if
    pontosB = pontosB + 1;
  }
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 65) {
    d1 = 1 + int((6 - 1 + 1) * random());
    atualizaPontos(); //atualização dos pontos aqui
  } else if (keyCode === 66) {
    d2 = 1 + int((6 - 1 + 1) * random());
    atualizaPontos(); //atualização dos pontos aqui
  }
  return false;
}
```

Pessoalmente ainda daria mais um passo no sentido de transformar também a geração do número aleatório numa função. Este passo torna o código mais simples, claro e reutilizavel:

```
function aleatorioEntre(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 65) {
    d1 = aleatorioEntre(1, 6); //gera aleatório de 1 a 6
    atualizaPontos();
  } else if (keyCode === 66) {
    d2 = aleatorioEntre(1, 6); //gera aleatório de 1 a 6
    atualizaPontos();
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado pelas correções e melhorias no código!